# How can we generate an orthogonal sinusodial signal to any other signal?

Tags: signal-analysis, digital-communications, orthogonal-signals

I have three signals which are 
\begin{align}
A&=\cos\left(2\pi ft + \frac \pi2\right)\\
B&=\cos\left(2\pi ft\right)\\
C&=\cos\left(2\pi ft + \frac {5\pi}4\right)
\end{align}

What i need to do is to draw two orthogonal sinusoidal signal D and E which are also orthogonal to the previous three. That is, D and E will be orthogonal to each other and they will be orthogonal with A, B and C too, at the same time. There is no constraint on the carrier frequency. How can i do it?

Comment: hm. Somethings strange here – what's the definition of orthogonality, and how do you apply it to $B$ and $C$?

Comment: Why do you "need" to do this? What is the application?

Comment: It's my homework actually, ahaha :'(

Comment: sinsusoids which are not same frequency are orthogonal which is the foundation for foueir series.

Comment: A and B are orthogonal but C is not orthogonal to either A or B; that said I take it your title is misleading as it would mean all signals A, B, C, D and E should be orthogonal to each other which can't be the case.

Comment: To solve this I suggest that you write out the formula for determining if two continuous time signals are orthogonal; try it with A, B, and C to show which of those are orthogonal and then try it with Ch Siva's comment above and then clarify where you are stuck if you still don't see it.